# ejabberd - persistent MUC messages on server restart

Tags: ejabberd

When I restart ejabberd I lose the MUC message history from all my chat rooms.

How can I configure ejabberd to retain the message history when it is restarted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, short term history is stored only in memory, so it is lost on restart.

Comment: That's a shame. i thought this might have been a more common scenario. Well I guess I'll have to roll my own solution then :-(

Comment: Well, that's actually quite rare to restart your ejabberd server. You can hot code upgrade, etc.

Comment: Can I hot load config changes? That's my immediate usecase, just in case I want to change config settings, etc.

Comment: yes, you can reload config and manually restart module for which the config has changed.

Comment: Oh thanks. That should buy me some breathing space until my app is a global phenomenon and I need to have a cluster of resilient chat servers :-)